# Отстает системное время в debian

Tags: linux, debian

Отстает **системное** время в debian. Проблема старая, была еще на lenny осталась и по сей день. Пережила и смену жесткого  диска и блока питания. 
При этом аппаратные часы идут точно. (При перезагрузки время восстанавливается) 
Раньше проблема особо не волновала т.к. в 23:59 настроена синхронизация. Однако недавно понадобилось заходить удаленно, при этом постоянно перед соединением приходится запускать синхронизацию времени.
Для этого делаю следующие

```
 sudo ntpdate-debian
```

Если время различается то при удаленном подключении выводится ошибка о не совпадении времени. За сутки часы отстают на 1-2 мин. примерно.
В какую сторону копать?

Comment: Значит не такие уж и точные часы или это виртуальная машина?

Comment: Может, после перезагрузки просто синхронизация сама запускалась? Если перезагрузиться в биос, время там будет точное или отстающее?

Comment: опишите, пожалуйста, прямо в вопросе (нажав [edit]), динамику и величину отставания. и уточните там же, с чем связана необходимость «запускать синхронизацию», и как вы её проделываете.

Comment: andreymal нет, если при загрузки войти в биос время точное

Comment: поставьте пакет *ntp*. это демон синхронизации времени, настроек по умолчанию обычно достаточно. и не запускайте `ntpdate`. // настроек не понадобится, если у компьютера есть свободный «выход» в интернет. // и, если не секрет, откройте тайну, что же это за такое «удалённое подключение», требующее синхронизации времени?